# Regex Needed to allow mod-rewrite rule to work either with or without trailing slash?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Given the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /userprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

How can I have it work either with or without a trailing slash?

Bonus points, how can I verify `([^/]*)` contains only numerals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)(/?)$    /userprofile.php?user=$1   [L]
```

The above rule should match on these conditions:

- `user/123`
- `user/123/`

It will not match:

- `user/fred`
- `user/123fred`
- `user/fred123`

`([0-9]+)` means match any numeral with one or more digits. 
`(/?)$` means an optional match of a slash, followed by a mandatory end-of-string.

For extra credit, you can even use this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]{1,9})(/?)$    /userprofile.php?user=$1   [L]
```

Which tells it to match numbers between one and nine digits (the `{1,9}` thing). Useful as an input-validator.

Comment: Is `(?/)` valid regex? It looks like a lookahead, but it's not. It seems like it ought to be `/?`, which would make the slash optional.

Comment: @Lèse majesté Mm, correct. It's reversed from what it should be. Fixed.